# How to prevent SliverAppBar from fading out background image?

Tags: flutter

I have the following `SliverAppBar` inside a `CustomScrollView`:

```
  SliverAppBar(
    stretch: true,
    floating: false,
    pinned: true,
    expandedHeight: 300,
    flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
      stretchModes: [StretchMode.zoomBackground],
      background: (
        Image.asset("assets/$bgimg", fit: BoxFit.cover)
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

It works as expected, however, as the users scrolls back up over the SliverAppBar, the background image (placed inside a `FlexibleSpaceBar`) fades away. The actual fading apparently happens inside the actual FlexibleSpaceBar Widget, as peeking into the source files gives this :

`final double opacity = 1.0 - Interval(fadeStart, fadeEnd).transform(t);`

Video:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1NMn.jpg

I don't want the SliverAppBar to turn blue when the user scrolls back up. How do you prevent this behaviour and makes the background stay persistently at all times? Am I looking at the wrong widget?

I have tried setting the color property of SliverAppBar to transparent, but it still fades out.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm looking to do exactly the  same, e.g. prevent that fadeOut animation!

Comment: Me too, having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to define the value of collapsedHeight equal to the value of expandedHeight

Comment: unfortunately it completely stops animation :)